# Find a point after specific distance in straight line between 2 Points in google maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a straight line from P1 to P2 as shown below, drawn using google maps API. Latitude and Longitude is available for both of these points.

I want to find a point in between these straight line say (P) with latitude and longitude which is located after some distance from P1.

Eg : Say distance between P1 and P2 is 10 km, I want to find a point located 4 km after P1 in a straight line to P2.

[image]

```
 function markPointInStraightLine(LatLngP1,LatLngP2, distanceInKm) {
       // To do
       //LatLngP1 and LatLngP2 is of type 'google.maps.LatLng'
}
```

Comment: this is more of a math problem ...

Comment: @madalinivascu But I have a doubt whether it is helpful in finding the exact geographic coordinates for google maps API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the interpolate function from the google api geometry library

> Given two LatLng objects and value between 0 and 1, you may also
>   calculate a destination between them using the interpolate() method,
>   which performs spherical linear interpolation between the two
>   locations, where the value indicates the fractional distance to travel
>   along the path from the origin to the destination.

more info at [google api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry)

Comment: Thank you! I could achieve my requirement with this☺

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) of Maps JavaScript API. The geometry library provides `computeHeading()` method to define heading between two points and `computeOffset()` method to calculate point on the certain distance from an origin in the specified heading. Add `&libraries=geometry` parameter in Maps JavaScript API URL in order to use the geometry library in your application

The code snippet should be

```
function markPointInStraightLine(LatLngP1,LatLngP2, distanceInKm) {
    var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(LatLngP1,LatLngP2);
    var p = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(LatLngP1, distanceInKm*1000, heading);
    return p;
}
```

I hope this helps!